# diffrence between a[:,:,0] and a[:][:][0]

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Hi I was studying slicing in python and I found something strange and I don't understand

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 2, 3],
        [8, 5, 6]
    ]
])
```

```py
>>> a[:][:][0]
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])

>>> a[:,:,0]
tensor([[1, 4],
        [7, 8]])
```

I tried to pull out [[1,4,7,8]] from the corresponding torch list, so I entered a[:][:][0] and the result of it is [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]].
 Then, when I input a[:,:,0], then [[1,4,7,8]] appeared.
I thought they have no different but different result appeared.
the torch and numpy operators, there was an operation like a[:,0]. How exactly can it be different from a[:][0]?

Comment: Syntactically, there is no requirement that `a[:]` return something that is itself indexible. The two desugar to `a.__getitem__(slice(None), slice(None), 0)` and `a.__getitem__(slice(None)).__getitem__(slice(None)).__getitem__(0)`, respectively.

Comment: Please replace the images with text. There is nothing in them that cannot be presented as text.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots where you can use code. I've edited your message for this time -waiting for approval.

Comment: `a[:]` returns *the whole tensort*. `a[:][:][0]` is eequivalent to `a[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can see the first, `a[:][:][0]`, as several, chained calls to `__getitem__`. That means `a[:][:][0]` is roughly equivalent to this:

```
b = a[:]
c = b[:]
d = c[0]
```

Where `d` is the result. In your case, it returns the same thing as `a[0]`, because `a[:] == a`.

In contrast, `a[:,:,0]` will only call `__getitem__` **once** with parameters `slice(None), slice(None), 0`.

In your case, that's the first *slice* of your tensor on the third axis.